# Collection view crashes when image loading from NS document directory

Tags: view, collections, crash, directory, nsdocument

I loaded the image to collection view which is stored from NS Document directory, but the collection view crashes due to memory pressure.

Converted the image in to JPEG format also happening the same problem please give the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the answer for my question just load the image in cache.its handling the memory and increasing the image loading speed in collection view.